# Internet Explorer 9 - CSS Breaking

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have this mock up HTML/CSS website here that is working perfectly fine on Firefox/Chrome but on Internet Explorer, the organization of the page is breaking; footer div is coming to the header section). I have tried to debug it but no luck.

It would be great if you can take a look into it and give me some pointers.

https://www.csupomona.edu/~tahoang/tu-template/

Thanks!!

Comment: Problem only occurs in IE7 - can be seen in IE9 if Compatibility Mode is on.

Comment: No, that doesn't work :(

Comment: As noted by the two comments above, do make sure that you are not stuck in either Compatibility Mode and or Quirks Mode in Internet Explorer. I have had this issue before, the effect is good and then bad. It points out issues, etc. Make sure you are using the correct syntax in your HTML Doctype and also remember to call out a Doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also notice in the Footer that you having a bunch of the columns positioned relatively, there is no need for that. You may remove that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of duplicate IDs in use. I would start by fixing those.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.csupomona.edu%2F~tahoang%2Ftu-template%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Looks fine to me in IE 8, IE 9 and Chrome. Do you have compatibility view enabled in IE 9?

Comment: As Tim mentioned in this answer, you generally only want to use an ID once on a page. But, you are not limited to using a specific amount of classes. I would recommend using classes at all times, and if needed, use an ID once.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Also fix those duplicate IDs Tim mentions, but this Meta tag will fix all your IE9 problems ;)

Comment: Although IE=Edge is a great way to make sure anybody that has Internet Explorer isn't viewing the website in Quirks Mode/Compatibility Mode... But that wouldn't resolve this issue regardless...

Comment: Yeah, the problem is still there :(

Comment: It's most likely something to do with your absolutely-positioned elements - they no longer expand the height of the container, so the footer ends up near the top. Or it could be your floats not being cleared properly by the `clear` element...

Comment: I can see that you closed your Wrapper DIV too early, please remove the closing DIV and bring it down above the ending body tag.

Comment: I also notice in the Footer that you having a bunch of the columns positioned relatively, there is no need for that. You may remove that.

Comment: @AaronBrewer: Bingo! It's the wrapper div closing tag. I moved the script down at the bottom so that the page can be fully loaded before the script runs but I moved it one too many! Thank you!

Comment: @Noobie: You are very welcome, I made the my Comment an Answer. May you please accept it?